# create QWidget width HWND parent

Tags: c++, qt

OS Windows. Qt 5.5.1
I made library (dll) with GUI on Qt.
I connected it to new project. I have parent's hwnd. How to set parent for library-window (Qwidget)?
If use winapi SetParent(), then child window does not leave bounds the parent window.
I tried QWidget::create(WId window, bool initializeWindow, bool destroyOldWindow), but it is not working, because according to documentation the parameter window is ignored in Qt 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way that works, but there are unknown messages on the screen

```
windowsProc: No Qt Window found for event 0x24 (WM_GETMINMAXINFO), hwnd=0x0x110956.
windowsProc: No Qt Window found for event 0x83 (WM_NCCALCSIZE), hwnd=0x0x110956.
windowsProc: No Qt Window found for event 0x5 (WM_SIZE), hwnd=0x0x110956.
windowsProc: No Qt Window found for event 0x3 (WM_MOVE), hwnd=0x0x110956.
setGeometryDp: Unable to set geometry 640x480+0+0 on QWindow/''. Resulting geometry:  640x480+-760+-370 (frame: 8, 30, 8, 8, custom margin: 0, 0, 0, 0, minimum size: 0x0, maximum size: 16777215x16777215).
setGeometryDp: Unable to set geometry 640x480+0+0 on QWindow/''. Resulting geometry:  640x480+-760+-370 (frame: 8, 30, 8, 8, custom margin: 0, 0, 0, 0, minimum size: 0x0, maximum size: 16777215x16777215).
listLabels.size() 4
```

Let a parent window be an ownerWin, and a child one QWidget-window named childWin;

If to use SetWindowLongPtr, the desirable result is achieved (the child window overlaps the parent one), but the child window still is in the memory when the parent window closes.

To fix a problem I create one more child window (middleWin with a parent ownerWin.) using WinApi. After wrapping this window with QWidget using createWindowContainer() it stops working normally. Then using standard Qt methods we can link our QWidget window. So we have three windows: parent, intermediate and mine. Then I close middleWin using close().All that manipulations needs to insure that when ownerWin closes, also childWin closes as well. If SetWindowLongPtr is used, then childWin will always be above the parent window, but it works only if called after function show() in child window.

Below are the functions I use. First call setWinParent(), then showWindow(). 
In setWinParent() lines 1 through 5 is "black box" for me. I don't know why window is created that way.

```
void setWinParent(HWND ownerWin)
{
    HWND hwnd = (HWND)this->winId();
    DWORD exStyle = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) ;//1
    DWORD style   = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE);//2
    WCHAR className[256];//3
    GetClassName(hwnd, className,256);//4
    HWND newHwnd = CreateWindowEx(exStyle, className, NULL, style,//5
                                  CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
                                  CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
                                  ownerWin, NULL, qWinAppInst(), NULL);
    QWindow *qw=QWindow::fromWinId((WId)newHwnd);
    QWidget* qWidget = createWindowContainer(qw);
    qWidget->show();
    this->setParent(qWidget);
    this->setWindowFlags(Qt::Window);
    qWidget->close();    
}
void showWindow(HWND ownerHwnd)
{
    show();
    SetWindowLongPtr((HWND)this->winId(), GWLP_HWNDPARENT, (LONG)ownerHwnd);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is a long-running issue with Qt on Windows (and other platforms). You'll have to find a way to hook into the parent window to catch mouse and keyboard events, etc. to propagate to your Qt child window. The internal Qt code for this is perpetually a work in progress.

There's a good page about these issues and the subject in general [here](https://gist.github.com/torarnv/c5dfe2d2bc0c089910ce). Here's the [bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-41186) discussing the issue, as well.

Note: `QAxWidget` isn't exactly helpful, either. It looks promising, but suffers the same issues with event propagation.

Comment: that would be `nativeEvent` in Qt5. Question was about re-parenting, not event-handling but apparently OP solves xy-problem

Comment: Ideally, yes, `nativeEvent` would work. Unfortunately, it doesn't really. You can't tell the parent (native) window to send focus, keyboard, and mouse events if it doesn't know the child (Qt) window supports them.

Comment: Good point that he doesn't reference events, but it's part of the larger issue that Qt doesn't handle native windows properly. You can *do* it, but it doesn't integrate.

Comment: it just doesn't use them completely, except receiving those from API. this allows Qt to be recompiled without support of any window system: e.g. to render directly to screen using linux kernel framebuffer - no X11 OR Wayland required

Answer (score 0):

In pyqt4 on windows you can use this. Surely you can find something in c++

```
import win32gui
from PyQt4.QtGui import QDialog
    
class MyCustomDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        if isinstance(parent, int):
            QDialog.__init__(self, None)
            win32gui.SetParent(self.winId(), parent) #<-this set the parent window
        else:
            QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
```

Answer (score -2):

> The parameter window is ignored in Qt 5. Please use
>   QWindow::fromWinId() to create a QWindow wrapping a foreign window and
>   pass it to QWidget::createWindowContainer() instead.

What's unclear about the Qt documentation?

```
QWindow *wndParent = QWindow::fromWinId(hwnd); // hwnd - your WId
if(wndParent) 
{
    QWidget *parent = QWidget::createWindowContainer(wndParent);
    if(parent)
        // ...
}
else
{
    // unsupported window...
}
```

Comment: My window is already QWidget. If I make make wrapping  for parent window, then I can myWindow->setParent(wrapped parent). But parent window becomes broken: no repaint, no mouse events, no resize

Comment: Also from the docs: "Note: The resulting QWindow should not be used to manipulate the underlying native window (besides re-parenting), or to observe state changes of the native window. Any support for these kind of operations is incidental, highly platform dependent and untested." Windows is not properly supported in this way by Qt.

Comment: @Владимир  you have  to use original widget for those.  Why you need hwd for parenting your window, if you already got Qt object? Qt framework isn't wrapper around API , it is an abstraction of GUI on its own, which track and stores states and handles events in its own way. All winodows api or x11 widgets are "windows"/"widgets".  Qt widget might be just a rendered object (non-native widget) that doesn't exist in API.

Comment: My *.dll has GUI. Main program will be on MSVS without QT. I want that window of my dll will be closed automatically when main program will be closed, also my window must be above the window of main program. Because of it, the parent for my-dll-window must be main program, but it is not QWidget.